# Operations in sortableAttributes (CListView)

Tags: list, sorting, yii

I want to give some operation in sortableAttributes like difference between vote_up and vote_down.

Is it possible?

```
'sortableAttributes'=>array(
            'id','created','vote_up-vote_down'=>'Votes',
),
```